# Laravel 5.4 redirect to login if unauthenticated

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a custom login page for my laravel app. However, i have modified my Handler.php to first look like this

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        if ($request->expectsJson()) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
        }

        return redirect()->guest('login');
    }
```

and even tried like this

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        if ($request->expectsJson()) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
        }

        return redirect('login');
    }
```

However, once I get to login, i get this error

[image]

How can i fix this problem?.

Comment: You are getting this error because it's on a redirect loop, it's probably because login route is also going through your "unauthenticated" method, so exclude login route from it

Comment: That was the issue that was causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

in the `web.php`

```
Route::get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function() {
//  Route::auth();
```

in the login controller

```
public function login(){
        return view('login-register');
    }
```

in the `handler.php`

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        if ($request->expectsJson()) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
        }

      return redirect()->guest('login');
    }
```

Comment: This didn't worked for me. It gives me 403 error instead.